# Interaction with Chess Pieces in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to make a chess game in java using JFrame and Java.awt and I can't figure out how to make the player able to interact with the pieces on screen.

Comment: Can you please share the work that you have done so far?

Comment: Can you make methods for something like `onMouseDrag()` for the cheese pieces? Or something like `onClick()`?

Answer (score 0):

First, your chess board should be a JPanel, not a JFrame. 
then you have several choices about how to design the rest.

One way would be for your pieces to be ImageIcons that you place appropriately, and add a MouseListener to determine which piece is selected (ButtonDown event), and whether it is legal for that player to interact with that piece.If it is legal, use the ButtonUp event to determine and where it is to go, and whether that is legal. Then re-draw the content of the cells affected.